Is it natural to use "nor" after affirmatives? E.g.: "They are happy, nor need we worry."
one of the meanings of "nor" from collinsdictionary.com:

nor:
(used after an affirmative statement, to introduce a reinforcing negative)
(used after an affirmative clause, or as a continuative, in the sense of "and not")
(1) They are happy, nor need we worry.
(2) He works from dawn to dusk, nor does he pause for rest.

Do (1) and (2) sound natural to you?
Is such a usage of "nor" correct nowadays or incorrect because it's archaic?
Can I use it or should I avoid it?

It doesn't seem idiomatic to me. It may be an archaic style, I'm surprised the dictionary doesn't say that.

The dictionary is correct.  that 'nor' in those sentences is just an alternative way of saying "And ... not". It is not 'archaic', just formal.

They say that is AmE usage. I dispute that and have never seen or heard it. Maybe in Appalachia or whatever.

Any use of "nor" is a bit "elevated" today. I'm not suggesting it's inappropriate, even in casual conversation, but the more casual the tone, the less likely to encounter it. Even common patterns like "neither/nor" are likely to be rephrased (e.g. "I like neither this nor that" -> "I don't like either one"; "Neither Billy nor Sue can come" -> "Both Billy and Sue can't come." I see no reason for a learner to avoid patterns like these... but yes, the pattern in the question is so rare as to be a good idea to avoid for everyday usage.

The dictionary is correct.  that 'nor' in those sentences is just an alternative way of saying "And ... not". It is not 'archaic', just formal or literary. Information gathered from guests, political support confirmed by attendance, bonds of comradeship forged by fellow enthusiasts, gifts of priceless tea bowls and many other spin-offs arose from these gatherings. Nor should the socially competitive nature of the tea ceremony be overlooked. - The Samurai by Stephen Turnbull, 1977

@Lambie - Stephen Turnbull is British; he attended Cambridge University where he gained his first degree. He currently holds 2 MAs in Theology and Military History and a PhD for his research on Kakure Kirishitan from the University of Leeds, where he is presently a lecturer in Far Eastern Religions.

@MichaelHarvey I dispute that it is AmE. Your guy there is British. I said this very clearly with regard to American English. The Collins entry says this under American English: 3. (used after an affirmative clause, or as a continuative, in the sense of and not)
They are happy, nor need we worry I dispute that.

Here's an example of its use, from someone from Baltimore in 1901 writing a letter to the editor of Dawn, a magazine devoted to the anti-vivisection movement.  I would not characterize the initial clause in the sentence I've bolded as an unqualifiedly affirmative statement.  Even as it asserts rights it is on the defensive. There is an unspoken "we do not need to worry what people think who say we have no such rights". Hence, nor.

We have a perfect right to capture, confine and kill animals at our need or pleasure, and we do so all over the world every day. We slay them by millions, even causing great suffering to them, and consume their carcasses. We have the same right to pursue them in sport, nor need we be troubled about how much or how little pain we cause them; and the same right to use them in scientific investigation, notwithstanding it may cause them torture. Brutes exist for us, and there is no moral obligation to guard them from suffering in any matter that is for our necessity or convenience. Accordingly, it is perfectly right to capture wild animals and shut them up in cages for purposes of education or entertainment. All that we need be careful about is not to confer pain merely for its own sake. This would brutalize ourselves.

I think you need a polemical context to use the construction to advantage. Short, terse sentences like those Collins provides as examples seem very odd, though the second one has some semantic basis for using "nor" since the first clause tells us he works long days. "nor does he" could be paraphrased there with emphatic "and":  "and he does not stop to rest", which is something like "and, mind you, he does not even stop to rest."
